# Async task not supporting in android 9.0 (Pie)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-asynctask, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-9.0-pie

I was working on my code. it was working fine on version 8(Oreo) after that I got an update of android v 9.0 (Pie) and the app stopped working suddenly. after checking I got a error message om my Asyn task stating the below error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.global.exch, PID: 25112
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:182)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:150)
    at com.global.exch.Dataholder.getApi(Dataholder.java:100)
    at com.global.exch.MainActivity$QuotesData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:391)
    at com.global.exch.MainActivity$QuotesData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:386)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:182) 
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:150) 
    at com.global.exch.Dataholder.getApi(Dataholder.java:100) 
    at com.global.exch.MainActivity$QuotesData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:391) 
    at com.global.exch.MainActivity$QuotesData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:386) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.global.exch-sEcnUuVsCYjXlnxJddVQAA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:718)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:801)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1023)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5780)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:200)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1660)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Can anyone help me out what is the exact issue for this as it was working fine earlier.
thank you in advance.

Comment: java reflection was limited in 9.0 kindly check : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

Comment: The error is clear: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory"` you are trying to load a class from apache commons logging which fails. Check your code and don't use classes from this library anymore.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue but After Adding the below code in my manifest file the issue got resolved

for reference you can also check this url:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28

**manifest.xml**

```
<application
        ...
         android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
       ...>

<uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you.. It worked for me.. You save my day. Happy Coding.. @frared

Comment: You saved my day dude. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

**How to update the existing project in androidx.**

does not need to add the extra permission & code, dependencies,...

0.1): changes into the  compileSdkVersion 29

0.2): Refactor-> Migrate to androidX then

Just add the following code in the project "ASDF":

1): add the XML directory,

1.1): Add the following code in XML, Code is below: i.e.

```
<application

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
<trust-anchors>
<certificates src="system"/>
</trust-anchors>
</base-config>
</network-security-config>

>
```

2): add the following code in the in manifest file:

2.1): within application tag the (manifest->application) add the following code:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

2.2): outside application tag the (manifest->application) add the following code:

```
<application>

 <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false"/>

</application>
```

**be happy and share your feedback** with me Thank you**